# Game engine for Html5

Tags: html, game-engine, craftyjs

I am trying to develop a game using Html5 for mobile App(iphone/ Android). Plz suggest  which html5 game engine wil use. I found Crafty and Impact game engine

[enter link description here](http://buildnewgames.com/introduction-to-crafty/)

[enter link description here](http://impactjs.com/)

Whether its will support all mobiles ? or any other html5 game engine for especially mobiles?

Tools which need to support
spirte animation, collision between spirte, Touch, accolometer, onPause & onResume ...

Answer (score 2):

For mobile game development, have you considered using something like one of the following game development tools?

Construct 2, GameMaker, GameSalad, Stencyl

Comment: Construct 2 is really fantastic. Especially for HTML5. So easy to use, one my favorite best prototyping tools. I've never personally made anything release worthy in it as I prefer to code to events, but I know quite a few people who have.

Comment: construct 2 wil support Accelerometer ?

Comment: I believe so with the new "touch object"